# Spring boot application shutting down on AWS

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot web application running on Production deployed on Amazon Web Servers. I have create two instances of my Web applications. But sometimes one/both instance(s) automatically stops. I can't understand how the process are killed automatically.

This issue is affecting many users experience. I am using Spring Boots default properties for tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Check your application.properties for endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true.

Perhaps the shutdown endpoint is getting called by someone.

Also, scan your code for any 'System.exit'

Also, the jvm may be crashing...

Is it stopping gracefully? Are there any logs?

Comment: By default endpoints.shutdown.enabled is false and we are not overriding it. No System.exit. The Java process running my service is getting killed on both the production boxes on AWS. How can I get embedded tomcat logs?

Comment: check the directory {your sb dir}/work/tmp/ there should be a file called spring.log

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:

```
springBoot {
    mainClass = ''
    executable = true
    buildInfo()
}
```

executable needs to be changed to false